# Deleting Elastic beanstack created s3 buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have created elestic beanstack (EB) app and it created s3 buckets.

When I try deleting S3 buckets related to EB , it gives error *Insufficient permissions to delete bucket
After you or your AWS admin have updated your IAM permissions to allow s3:DeleteBucket, choose delete bucket. Learn more about Identity and Access Management in Amazon S3*

When I check EB , it show no application or environments at present,(I might have deleted yesterday)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to go to the bucket's permissions, and **delete its bucket policy** first. The bucket policy on the EB bucket stops you from deleting it.

Comment: Thanks, if I close my Aws account, will the EB service stop? I am  a newbie into AWS and accidentally got charged while learning things

Comment: @AnoopKGeorge You can just delete the EB yourself. If you don't use it you won't be paying for it.